# Sencha touch native android app not loading Malayalam fonts

Tags: android, fonts

I am facing an issue in rendering Malayalam fonts in the Sencha application build for Android platform. 
Some of the devices in which we found the issues are Sony Ericsson XPERIA & Micromax Canvas A110 .

We have also tried adding custom fonts to the Sencha app using font face, when the app is converted into android native app, the fonts are not applied.

Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance